# Compose - Display a composable above keyboard on Z axis

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I want to display full-screen content on top of software keyboard in Compose. You can see my use case on the following gif:

[image: Use-case]

This screen's layout looks like this, with `ImageViewer` on top of content to support a kind of shared element transition:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.imePadding(),
    topBar = {...},
    content = {...},
    bottomBar = {...}
)

ImageViewer(...)
```

What are my options here? I do know that I can achieve it by opening `ImageViewer` in a different `Window`, but then I would lose the ability to perform a transition like this since the new `Window` would have its own composition. Is it possible to achieve this with compose only?

Answer (score 0):

you can always close the soft keyboard via this code

```
 val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current


keyboardController?.hide()
```

call the hide method on the image's clickable.

Comment: I don't think they wanted to close the keyboard.

Comment: @KristyWelsh does he want to show the image above the keyboard?

Comment: I don't know, but that what his question is.

Comment: Yes, ideally I would like to show the image above the keyboard. My current solution includes hiding the keyboard and showing it back up when gallery is closed, but I don't particularly like it